# woocommerce hooks and is_shop() / is_archive()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to do two things:

1. remove the breadcrumbs in category pages, but leave it in single product pages.
2. remove the title from the shop page.

For the breadcrumbs, I tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
if( is_archive() ){
    add_action( 'init', 'porto_remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
    function porto_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
    } 
}
```

(without the conditional tag it does work, or if I change the conditional to `if(1<2)` instead).
no matter what archive page i'm displaying, with the code above the breadcrumbs is shown.

About the second problem, this code doesn't work either:

```
if( is_shop() ){
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title' , 'woo_hide_page_title' );

    function woo_hide_page_title() {

        return false;

    }
}
```

There's still title in shop page after running this code. I guess the solution for both problems are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30650/need-to-check-is-archive-during-init

Comment: Didn't really find a solution there

Comment: `init` is too early to use `is_archive()`. You should consider nesting these conditionals inside of your callbacks, and using hooks that fire later in the load process.

Comment: Ok thanks, I solve this by change the hook to `template_redirect`